# PHP: why this select count doesn't function properly with the Group by?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY` in my PHP page.

I have a database that looks like this:

```
id   name

1    W1
2    W1
3    W1
4    W2
5    W2
6    W4
7    W5
8    W4
```

My php count function looks like this:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM packets GROUP BY name");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
$num2 = $row2[0];

echo $num2;
```

However, the code above always returns a number `2`!

Based on the example above (my MYSQL data), it should return `4` but it always returns `2`.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it should return 5? Based on your given data, it can return either 3, 2 or 1 since you haven't provided any order. What's your requirement?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh, TYPO.. I MEANT TO TYPE 4... calm down maaaaaan...

Comment: This is the result when I run that sql on my MYSQL with that data. w1=3, w2=2, w4=2, w5=1 in this order. row2[0] will be 3 based on this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the query you intended to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM packets
```

As you might expect, this would count the number of distinct names in your packets table.

In your case, packets `W1`, `W2`, `W4`, and `W5` appear, so the distinct count is 4 (not 5 as you perhaps expected).

Comment: Why would that return 5?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You're right, but I think the OP is even confused about his own data.  Let me update.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no I'm not confused about anything! where did you get that idea from?!

Comment: @DavidHope Now this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: this works. and in my question i said 5 instead of 4 and that was just a typo.. no confusion. ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, what's getting ridiculous?!

Comment: OK I got you...you mean to say that you knew exactly what you were trying to count, but looking at the downvotes many disagreed with you.

Comment: Ah Sunday night on Stack Overflow...I see red everywhere and I wouldn't have it any other way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, lol... I honestly doubt that every downvoter on STO knows why they actually downvoted a valid question/answer if you were to ask them! so many trigger happy users on STO...

Comment: keep up the charm no need to worry about the down votes or down voters